# how to solve ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function/error definition. in soliduty

Tags: compiler-errors, solidity, smartcontracts, pragma, remix

i was pretty successful in running my auction code until maybe some keys were pressed and now this error started showing, I am unable to figure out why this error is showing

ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function/error definition.

the error is in line 79 where the event is declared

what could it possibly be I check my pragma statement its pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Auction {
address payable internal auction_owner; 
uint256 public auction_start; 
uint256 public auction_end; 
uint256 public highestBid;
address public highestBidder;

enum auction_state {
CANCELLED, STARTED,ENDED
}
address[] bidders;

mapping(address => uint) public bids; 

auction_state public STATE;



modifier an_ongoing_auction() { require(block.timestamp <= auction_end);
_;
}

modifier only_owner() { require(msg.sender == auction_owner);
_;
}

function MyAuction (uint _biddingTime, address payable  _owner) public {
     auction_owner = _owner; 
     auction_start = block.timestamp;
    auction_end = auction_start + _biddingTime* 1 minutes;
     STATE = auction_state.STARTED;
    if (block.timestamp>auction_end){
        STATE=auction_state.ENDED;
        auction_owner.transfer(highestBid);
        bids[highestBidder]=0;
        
    } 

}

function bid() public payable an_ongoing_auction returns (bool){ 

    require(bids[msg.sender] + msg.value > highestBid, "can't bid, Make a higher Bid" );

    highestBidder = msg.sender; 
    highestBid = msg.value; 
    bidders.push(msg.sender);
    bids[msg.sender] = bids[msg.sender] + msg.value; 
    emit BidEvent(highestBidder, highestBid);
    return true; 
    }
    
}

function withdraw() public payable returns (bool){
   // address payable rec = msg.sender;
    require(block.timestamp > auction_end , "can't withdraw, Auction is still open");
    uint amount= bids[msg.sender];
    bids[msg.sender] = 0; 
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount); 
    emit WithdrawalEvent(msg.sender, amount);
    return true;
}
function cancel_auction() only_owner an_ongoing_auction public returns (bool) {
     STATE = auction_state.CANCELLED;
    emit CanceledEvent("Auction Cancelled", block.timestamp,highestBid); 
    return true;
}
function time_remain() an_ongoing_auction public view returns (uint256){
uint256 timeleft= auction_end - block.timestamp;
return timeleft; 

}

event BidEvent(address highestBidder, uint256 highestBid); 

event WithdrawalEvent(address withdrawer, uint256 amount);

event CanceledEvent(string message, uint256 time, uint256 highestBid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick copy and paste of your code to remix shows that you have a misplaced closing brace after the bid function. If you remove that misplaced closing brace, your code should compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean and styling your code so that it's easy to find the mistake.
and solidity will need to specify the SPDX License to avoided the warning as well here is the code should be:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Auction {
address payable internal auction_owner; 
uint256 public auction_start; 
uint256 public auction_end; 
uint256 public highestBid;
address public highestBidder;

enum auction_state {
CANCELLED, STARTED,ENDED
}
address[] bidders;

mapping(address => uint) public bids; 

auction_state public STATE;



modifier an_ongoing_auction() { require(block.timestamp <= auction_end);
_;
}

modifier only_owner() { require(msg.sender == auction_owner);
_;
}

function MyAuction (uint _biddingTime, address payable  _owner) public {
     auction_owner = _owner; 
     auction_start = block.timestamp;
    auction_end = auction_start + _biddingTime* 1 minutes;
     STATE = auction_state.STARTED;
    if (block.timestamp>auction_end){
        STATE=auction_state.ENDED;
        auction_owner.transfer(highestBid);
        bids[highestBidder]=0;
        
    } 

}

function bid() public payable an_ongoing_auction returns (bool){ 

    require(bids[msg.sender] + msg.value > highestBid, "can't bid, Make a higher Bid" );

    highestBidder = msg.sender; 
    highestBid = msg.value; 
    bidders.push(msg.sender);
    bids[msg.sender] = bids[msg.sender] + msg.value; 
    emit BidEvent(highestBidder, highestBid);
    return true; 
    }

    
function withdraw() public payable returns (bool){
   // address payable rec = msg.sender;
    require(block.timestamp > auction_end , "can't withdraw, Auction is still open");
    uint amount= bids[msg.sender];
    bids[msg.sender] = 0; 
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount); 
    emit WithdrawalEvent(msg.sender, amount);
    return true;
}
function cancel_auction() only_owner an_ongoing_auction public returns (bool) {
     STATE = auction_state.CANCELLED;
    emit CanceledEvent("Auction Cancelled", block.timestamp,highestBid); 
    return true;
}
function time_remain() an_ongoing_auction public view returns (uint256){
uint256 timeleft= auction_end - block.timestamp;
return timeleft; 

}

event BidEvent(address highestBidder, uint256 highestBid); 

event WithdrawalEvent(address withdrawer, uint256 amount);

event CanceledEvent(string message, uint256 time, uint256 highestBid);
    
}
```